# Having an issues getting started with making my first Ionic app

Tags: web-apps

I've been trying off and on now for a while to create and understand how to use ionic/angular/firebase and I've given up each time.

My main struggle is that every tutorial I try does things a little bit differently. Also, most of them are usually missing one tiny thing that the author forgot or expects is basic knowledge so I go to another tutorial to try to fill in the blank but they don't mesh well. Or the article is just out of date.

What's the best way for a beginner to learn how to use Ionic?

Comment: highly recommend a company which specializes in Ionic development https://itmaster-soft.com/en/ionic-app-development-services